# how to import state of pandas dataframe to second .py file

Tags: python, pandas

so, toward the end of my first file; we'll call /`file.py`.

```
def get_excel_data(self):
        """Places excel data into pandas dataframe"""

        # excel_data = pandas.read_excel(self.find_file())

        for extracted_archive in self.find_file():
            excel_data = pandas.read_excel(extracted_archive)

            # print(excel_data)

            columns = pandas.DataFrame(columns=excel_data.columns.tolist())
            excel_data = pandas.concat([excel_data, columns])

            excel_data.columns = excel_data.columns.str.strip()
            excel_data.columns = excel_data.columns.str.replace("/", "_")
            excel_data.columns = excel_data.columns.str.replace(" ", "_")

            total_records = 0
            num_valid_records = 0
            num_invalid_records = 0

            for row in excel_data.itertuples():
                mrn = row.MRN
                total_records += 1

                if mrn in ("", " ", "N/A", "NaT", "NaN", None) or math.isnan(mrn):
                    # print(f"Invalid record: {row}")
                    num_invalid_records += 1
                    # total_invalid = num_invalid_records + dup_count
                    excel_data = excel_data.drop(excel_data.index[row.Index])
                    # continue
                else:
                    # print(mrn) # outputs all MRN ids
                    for row in excel_data.itertuples():
                        num_valid_records += 1

                        continue   

            with open("./logs/metrics.csv", "a", newline="\n") as f:
                csv_writer = DictWriter(f, ['date', 'total_records', 'processed', 'skipped', 'success_rate'])
                # csv_writer.writeheader()

                currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()
                success_rate = num_valid_records / total_records * 100
                csv_writer.writerow(dict(date=currentDT,
                                        total_records=total_records,
                                        processed=num_valid_records,
                                        skipped=num_invalid_records,
                                        success_rate=num_valid_records / total_records * 100))

            return self.clean_data_frame(excel_data)

    def clean_data_frame(self, data_frame):
        """Cleans up dataframes"""
        for col in data_frame.columns:
            if "date" in col.lower():
                data_frame[col] = pandas.to_datetime(data_frame[col],
                                                     errors='coerce', infer_datetime_format=True)
                data_frame[col] = data_frame[col].dt.date
        data_frame['MRN'] = data_frame['MRN'].astype(int).astype(str)

        return data_frame

    def get_mapping_data(self):
        map_data = pandas.read_excel(config.MAPPING_DOC, sheet_name='main')
        columns = pandas.DataFrame(columns=map_data.columns.tolist())
        return pandas.concat([map_data, columns])
```

in my second file I would like to keep that end state; and do another iteration for instance.... `second_file.py`

```
def process_records(self, records, map_data, completed=None, errors=None):
    """Code to execute after webdriver initialization."""
    series_not_null = False
    try:
        num_attempt = 0

        for record in data_frame.itertuples(): # not working
            print(record)
            series_not_null = True
            mrn = record.MRN

            self.navigate_to_search(num_attempt)
            self.navigate_to_member(mrn)
            self.navigate_to_assessment()
            self.add_assessment(record, map_data)
            self.driver.switch_to.parent_frame() # not working
            sleep(.5)

            error_flag = self.close_member_tab(self.driver, mrn, error_flag)

    except Exception as exc:
        if series_not_null:
            errors = self.process_series_error(exc)

    return completed, error
```

both have `import pandas`

Comment: So your goal is to have code in 1 file, get a pandas dataframe, do some stuff with it, and then start another script that works on the same dataframe? Can you just save the dataframe as a pickle file at the end of file1 and then load it in in file2?

Comment: I have not heard of a pickle file; could you give me an example?

Comment: @Jacobr365 please do not make fun of my goals....

Comment: please explain how i have done anything even close to making fun of your goals... i asked for clarification, and if a simple solution would work. You said you hadn't heard of the solution and asked for an example, so i gave you an answer and an example, like you asked...... If you have found some way to take this as "making fun of your goals", then that is on you, because i have done no such thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save your dataframe in a pickle file like this. it is also worth noting that you can store most anything in a pickle file. here is a link to some info here: [pickle info](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/02/what-is-pickle-in-python/)

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle

x = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6],'c':[7,8,9]})

#this will create a file called pickledata.p that will store the data frame
with open('pickledata.p', 'wb') as fh:   #notice that you need the 'wb' for the dump
    pickle.dump(x, fh)

#to load the file do this
with open('pickledata.p', 'rb') as fh:   #you need to use 'rb' to read
    df = pickle.load(fh)

#you can now use df like a normal dataframe
print(df)
```

you dont actually need the '.p' extension for a pickle file, i just like it.

so you save your dataframe at the end of script one, and then load it in at the start of script 2.

Comment: appreciate the insight, Jac. +1 for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Dataframe.to_pickle`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) and [`pandas.read_pickle`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_pickle.html):

To persist

```
df.to_pickle('./dataframe.pkl')
```

To load

```
df = pd.read_pickle('./dataframe.pkl')
```

Comment: appreciate the insight, Chris. +1 for your effort.